# It's possibile select one radio without name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I need to use attribute name so I can use "name" attribute for radio button.
I know that the code for radio button with exclusive choice is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="radio">
<input type="checkbox" name="radio">
```

Anyone can help me to choice another method to render the radio with exclusive choice without name attribute?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking but if there is no  group then checkbox is probably what you want. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also why would you not use a name? if used in a form the control must have a name or it won't submit

Comment: What are you using the `name` for if it's not for grouping? If you need to distinguish the buttons in a group, you should use the `value` for it.

Comment: One reason a person might remove a name attribute is to [prevent values from being submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125638/how-can-i-exclude-html-form-radio-button-values-from-being-submitted).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could use a `class`:-

```js
$('.radio').change(function() {
  $('.radio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radio">
```

or even just by the `type`:-

```js
var radios = $('[type="radio"]');

radios.change(function() {
  radios.not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: Why would you ever need a configuration like this? It  makes no sense and would never submit if used in a form. Form controls with no `name` won't be submitted

Comment: @charlietfl I agree using the name attribute as intended is always a good idea, but I dont always have radios even in a form, or if i do i dont want the for to be submitted regularly, i want it done with ajax, in which case not all inputs even need a name. But for radios I dont get why you wouldnt just use the name attribute.

Comment: ...you should also be listening to the `change` event rather than the `click` event.

Comment: @charlietfl there is no evidence from the question that this will be submitted.

Comment: @JoshCrozier agreed, I have updated the answer.

Comment: by the same token the question is so vague that use case is completely unknown. To be honest this whole question smells like an XY problem. Sometimes comments like the one I made are as much helpful for the OP as for the answerer. OP may have completely overlooked name issue for example

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something similar to @BG101 but wrap it in a function and allow any jQuery selector to be used so you could target multiple groups.

https://jsfiddle.net/53knnzho/

```js
function bindRadios(selector){
  $(selector).click(function() {
    $(selector).not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
};

bindRadios("#radio1, #radio2, #radio3");
bindRadios("#radio4, #radio5, #radio6");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' id='radio1' />
<input type='radio' id='radio2' />
<input type='radio' id='radio3' />
<br><br>
<input type='radio' id='radio4' />
<input type='radio' id='radio5' />
<input type='radio' id='radio6' />
```

Comment: This can use classes or ids or you could put them in a div and and do something like `bindRadios("div#div1 input[type=radio]")` to get all in that div/group.